# Why is fstream put function filling 4GB of space on my drive?

Tags: c++, fstream

For whatever reason, my program is filling up 4GB of space on my drive. Why?

I narrowed it down to this `for` loop using breakpoints:

```cpp
int blockPos = 1;
char blockAddressPos = 0x00;
for (int d = 0; d < img.width * img.height * img.channels; d++) {
    tf.write(blockPos, blockAddressPos, (char)img.data[d]);
    //printf("Byte write: %i\n", (unsigned int)img.data[d]);
    blockAddressPos++;
    break; // Debug purposes
    if (blockAddressPos >= 0xFF) {
        blockPos++;
        blockAddressPos = 0x00;
    }
}
```

The `tf.write()` function:

```cpp
void TableFormatter::write(int block, char blockAddr, char data) {
    if (_valid) {
        if (block == 0) {
            if (blockAddr <= 0x0F) {
                // Core file metadata is located here, disallow write access or shift address to 0x10

                blockAddr = 0x10;
                _states.write.TableMetadataWarning = true;
            }
        }

        unsigned int location = (block << 8) | blockAddr;
        _table.seekp(location, FileBeginning);
        _table.put(data);
    } else {
        _states.fileSignatureInvalid = true;
    }
}
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What compiler/OS are you using?  On many of them, `char` is signed and so `blockAddressPos >= 0xFF` is always false.

Comment: i am on windows using visual studio 2019

Comment: I'd add some debug code here: `_table.seekp(location, FileBeginning);`. To see if/when you're using a huge `location` value.

Comment: Also, what are the values of `img.width`, `img.height`, `img.channels`?  If they are negative, or if the multiplication overflows, the loop may continue until `d` overflows.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Without knowing how img.width and height is set or defined, any advice would be pure speculation. And one of that speculation is that probably exactly those are the problem.

Comment: the ```FileBeginning``` is ```#define FileBeginning std::ios_base::beg```

Comment: they should be 4 * 4 * 3 because the used image is 4x4 pixels with 3 color channels for each pixel

Comment: even if the loop is the problem, there is a break statement and the result is still the same, because i have tested this with the for loop and break statement as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [/J (Default char Type Is unsigned)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/j-default-char-type-is-unsigned?view=msvc-170), by default `char` is signed in Visual C++.  So after `blockAddressPos` exceeds `0x7F`, it wraps around and most likely becomes negative, e.g. `0x80 = -128`.

When you pass this negative value to `tf.write()`, the line `unsigned int location = (block << 8) | blockAddr;` promotes `blockAddr` to `int`, which sign-extends.  So you do the equivalent of `location = (block << 8) | 0xFFFFFF80`, which is where your ~4 GB comes from.

You probably want to change `blockAddressPos` and the `blockAddr` parameter to be `unsigned char`, or better, `uint8_t`.

(By the way, with that fixed, your test `blockAddressPos >= 0xFF` will write blocks of size 255 bytes, not 256; is that really what you want?)

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.